# Why is Bitcoin Core structured as a wallet? I know that it began as a wallet, but is it possible to make it like a GUI block explorer instead?

Tags: blockchain-explorer

I'm always frustrated when I open up Bitcoin Core, and then all I get is an empty wallet GUI. I see no information about the block-chain itself. When I want to see on-chain data, I have to go to centralized websites instead.

I would like to see Bitcoin Core be restructured as a GUI block explorer. Delete all the wallet features. Bitcoin Core is a really, really bad wallet, to be honest. Didn't Core developer Luke Dash Junior just lose his entire stash of 300 coins because he was using a internet-connected Bitcoin core as a hot wallet?

It is very bad practice to run a hot wallet, period. Private key information should never ever touch a internet connected computer. I use Electrum on TAILS for signing transactions, and I use Electrum on Windows as a watch only wallet.

I would like to see Bitcoin Core be a locally run self sovereign version of blockchain.com/explorer or mempool.space.

Answer (score 4):

> Delete all the wallet features.

This would be a breaking change as it prevents anyone who has used Bitcoin Core as wallet from being able to continue to use their wallets at all. AFAIK, no other software reads Bitcoin Core's wallet files, and the process of moving to another wallet can result in accidentally losing coins, a reduction in privacy, and is generally annoying to do.

While people could continue to use older versions if they did not want to change software, they would eventually find their software outdated and missing security fixes and feature updates that are relevant to the node part of Bitcoin Core. This would generally not be a good experience.

> Bitcoin Core is a really, really bad wallet, to be honest. Didn't Core developer Luke Dash Junior just lose his entire stash of 300 coins because he was using a internet-connected Bitcoin core as a hot wallet?

Individuals who use a software and fail to keep their coins secure is not a failing of the software itself. There are a lot of things that can go wrong that aren't related to the wallet being used.

> t is very bad practice to run a hot wallet, period. Private key information should never ever touch a internet connected computer. I use Electrum on TAILS for signing transactions, and I use Electrum on Windows as a watch only wallet.

Bitcoin Core does not require you to run it as a hot wallet. It can also be used in the same way that you use Electrum. Furthermore, Electrum can also be used as a hot wallet and has all of the same issues that running Bitcoin Core as a hot wallet does. Removing the wallet functionality doesn't change that, it just reduces the available wallet software.

> I would like to see Bitcoin Core be a locally run self sovereign version of blockchain.com/explorer or mempool.space.

Many of the features in block explorers are not useful to the average user. Block explorers maintain a database of every single address ever used. They also have to maintain a database of which transactions have spent which outputs. The vast majority of this information is completely irrelevant as very few people actually need to do random lookups in the blockchain. This information is also not useful to the operation of the node itself.

Most people are interested in looking for specific transactions and addresses. This is what a wallet does, and this is why a wallet is useful. It is a database that contains just the things that a particular person cares about, not the entire universe where the vast majority of transactions are irrelevant.

If you want to run your own block explorer, you can. Mempool.space is open source, you can run your own instance. There are other block explorer software such as esplora.